# How do I seed another data table's records with category information in another Excel data table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a data table, of which one of the columns is 'Categories'. It is a basic text column, but it has a finite set of strings (e.g. 'Utilities', 'Home', 'Medical', etc.) I would like to automatically seed another data table's columns with those category names, without having to use a pivot table.

A pivot table doesn't give me the kind of flexibility I need in using additional formulas to make calculations; in this particular example I need to combine the data from two similar data tables, but I need to apply some non-standard functions to the data before displaying them in the cells.

If a pivot table *can* do this, then I'd love to know how. Basically, my summary table is going to look like this:

```
Category | Spending
Home     | SUM(SUM(HOME_STUFF_FROM_WKSHT1) * 'EXCHANGE RATE', SUM(HOME_STUFF_FROM WKSHT2))
```

Comment: Some example of what you have and what result figures you're looking for would help understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

using the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18852645/1370425) to join the two tables, you can create a calculated Item for your newly combined pivot table. The first column from each table is used to create the row labels, and each *differently* named column after the first is used to create the row labels.

As you can see from the example, I used a conversion factor of 1.6 to convert my GP£ to US$, giving me a formula of `='GP£'*1.6+'US$'`

[image: Example]